# SQL history table design of hierarchical data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have some certain item data which include multiple sub items from different tables linked with foreign keys. As to show the customers the history of item with all related sub items, I need to store the data change in the database and there are a few options that come out.

1. Create _hist table with triggers of all the tables to store data whenever there is a change to any of the tables. All the changes are stored but it would be hard to grab the data of items from all the tables as there is no connection among _hist tables
2. Create a single history table with all the columns from all the tables.    As there is hierarchy of the items, it is not possible to store the changes with only one single row.

As none of the above works as expected, it ended up a history table was created with columns of Id, timestamp, etc. and an additional column to store the changes.

Whenever there is a change, we retrieve all the tables, transform the data into JSON format, and save it in the history table. The transformed JSON data is similar to the one below.

```
{
    "ItemId": 1,
    "ItemStatus": 100,
    "SubItmems": [
        {
            "SubItemId": 1,
            "ItemId": 1,
            "SubItemStatus": 200,
            "SubChildItems": [
                {
                    "SubChildItem": 1,
                    "SubItemId": 1,
                    "SubChildItemStatus": 300,
                },
                {
                    "SubChildItem": 2,
                    "SubItemId": 1,
                    "SubChildItemStatus": 400,
                },
            ],
        }
    ],
    "ItemTags": [
        {
            "TagId": 1,
            "TagStatus": "OK",
        },
    ],
}
```

However, the retrieving and transformation parts take time and we've got some performance issues.

I need to improve the current structure but haven't figured out an efficient one.

Kindly share ideas if you have any.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 14.0

Comment: Then I would go with Temporal tables if I where you. I hope I'll have the time to write an answer later today.

Comment: I just started to check Temporal tables. It's appreciated if you could give more insights.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas (don't know if applicable but sharing):

- An history table with only customerID, a date and the serialized JSON in a blob. A Trigger can call a SP which will do this job.(Recommended solution)
- An history table with an TableName, DateTime, ID, Field, OldValue, NewValue. Same Way, A trigger that add records.

If you want to have a clean a reliable history you'll have to play with trigger.
It all depends then the way you need to use this history (just reading or consuming it.)